# How do I get last record from a mysql column through php where several other query is running

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to get several user data (from a Voip Calling Card Database) to a web portal from multiple table where **Login**, **Name**, **Registration Date** taken from one table, **Last Successful Call** Date is in another table and Current User balance and Total Duration is in another table. Here is the demo screencap:

[image]

My problem is im not able to get the last call date which have to query and get the last or latest date from a list of total call history by filtering each user individually.

Codes are given below:

All of the needed data is in these 3 table "clientsshared, invoiceclients, calls,"

"clientsshared" holds Login & balance data.

"invoiceclients" holds Name and Account Creation Date.

"calls" holds call duration and all other call history

```
<div>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Login</th>
        <th>Full Name</th>
        <th>Reg.Date</th>
        <th>LastCall</th>
        <th>Current Balance</th>
        <th>Total Duration</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php 
         $sql="select c.login,cname.Name,cname.LastName,DATE_FORMAT(cname.Creation_Date,'%d-%m-%y')as regdate,cdr.call_start,c.account_state,sum(cdr.duration / 60) as total_duration from clientsshared as c
         left join invoiceclients as cname on cname.IdClient = c.id_client
         left join calls as cdr on cdr.id_client = c.id_client
         where c.id_reseller='10' group by c.id_client order by total_duration desc limit 100" ; 

        $result=$ db1->query($sql); 

        if($result){ 
        $i = 1; 
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){ 
            $login = $row->login; 
            $Name = $row->Name; 
            $LastName = $row->LastName; 
            $RegDate = $row->regdate; 
            $LastCall = $row->call_start; 
            $account_state = $row->account_state; 
            $total_duration = $row->total_duration; 
       ?>

      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $login; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Name. " ".$LastName; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $RegDate; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $LastCall; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo round($account_state,2); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo round($total_duration,2); ?></td>
      </tr>

      <?php 
        $i++; 
        } 
       } 
      ?>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**==== Updated Problem and Solved======**

**There is a new issue im facing, I've tried to add a new table by Left Join which is a payment history table but after joining this table the actual total Duration field giving wrong values**

New query is here:

```html
$sql = 
  "select c.login,cname.Name,cname.LastName,DATE_FORMAT(Creation_Date,'%m-%d-%y')as regdate, 
  (Select max(data) from payments where payments.id_client = c.id_client) as lastpayment,
  (Select max(call_start) from calls where calls.id_client = c.id_client) as lastcall, 
   c.account_state,sum(cdr.duration / 60) as total_duration from clientsshared as c

   left join invoiceclients as cname on cname.IdClient = c.id_client
   left join payments as p on p.id_client = c.id_client
   left join calls as cdr on cdr.id_client = c.id_client

   where c.id_reseller='10' group by c.id_client order by total_duration desc limit 100";
```

[image]

**Solved**
wow, Im not sure how it works but I just removed a `left join` and tried which output the correct value as expected ,

```html
    select c.login,cname.Name,cname.LastName,cname.Creation_Date as regdate, 
 (Select max(data) from payments where payments.id_client = c.id_client) as lastpayment,
 (Select max(call_start) from calls where calls.id_client = c.id_client) as lastcall, 
 c.account_state,sum(cdr.duration / 60) as total_duration 

 from clientsshared as c

 left join invoiceclients as cname on cname.IdClient = c.id_client
 left join calls as cdr on cdr.id_client = c.id_client

 where c.id_reseller='10' 

 group by c.id_client 

 order by total_duration desc
```

Comment: I do not see the column for last call date in your sql query. Can you tell from which table are you pulling last call date information?

Comment: Oh, its in "calls" table, actually all of the data i need is storred in those 3 tables mentioned in code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting it as an answer as it is too long:

As a said, I do not see the field for last call date in your select statement of $sql. If you have a direct column for last call date in Calls table then include it select statement. So your query should look something like this:

```
    select c.login,cname.Name,cname.LastName,DATE_FORMAT(Creation_Date,'%d-%m-%y')as regdate,(Select max(call_start) from calls where calls.id_client = c.id_client) as lastcall,
 c.account_state,sum(cdr.duration / 60) as total_duration from clientsshared as c
         left join invoiceclients as cname on cname.IdClient = c.id_client
         left join calls as cdr on cdr.id_client = c.id_client
         where c.id_reseller='10' group by c.id_client order by total_duration desc limit 100"
```

I have added **(Select max(cdr.call_start) from calls where calls.id_client = c.id_client)** in your query.

Comment: Thanks Abhy, I did as you said by adding "cdr.call_start" but its only giving the first record but I need the last entry from full list of call history, 

suppose in "calls" table it keeps all the call history for all user, I only need the last record (not the first) for each user.

Comment: wow, its seems working as I verified several times, http://i.imgur.com/Ei2nQYe.png

Just one more thing needed, I only need date, so how do i do that ?

Comment: Great!! You can cast the result as date. `Cast((Select max(cdr.call_start) from calls where calls.id_client = c.id_client) as date)`
P.S Please mark it as answer if it helped you.
Thanks!!

Comment: well, thanks , I will try this , but I already figured other way, please check if its safe or correct ?

`DATE_FORMAT((Select max(call_start) from calls where calls.id_client = c.id_client),'%d-%m-%y') as lastcall`

Comment: That should work as well. I think you are already using it for regdate.

Comment: Cast is not working : `select c.login,cname.Name,cname.LastName,DATE_FORMAT(Creation_Date,'%d-%m-%y')as regdate,Cast((Select max(cdr.call_start) from calls where calls.id_client = c.id_client) as date), c.account_state,sum(cdr.duration / 60) as total_duration from clientsshared as c
          left join invoiceclients as cname on cname.IdClient = c.id_client
          left join calls as cdr on cdr.id_client = c.id_client
          where c.id_reseller='10' group by c.id_client order by total_duration desc limit 100`

Comment: My bad.. It wont work as you are using Mysql. It is SQL server specific. Please use date_format function

Comment: You are welcome. Do not forget to mark it as answer. Thanks!!

Comment: Hello Abhay, there is a new issue im facing, I've tried to add a new table by `Left Join` which is a payment history table but after joining this table the actual total Duration field giving wrong values ,

Comment: new code is here `$sql = "select c.login,cname.Name,cname.LastName,DATE_FORMAT(Creation_Date,'%m-%d-%y')as regdate, (Select max(data) from payments where payments.id_client = c.id_client) as lastpayment, (Select max(call_start) from calls where calls.id_client = c.id_client) as lastcall, c.account_state,sum(cdr.duration / 60) as total_duration from clientsshared as c 
left join invoiceclients as cname on cname.IdClient = c.id_client 
left join payments as p on p.id_client = c.id_client
left join calls as cdr on cdr.id_client = c.id_client 
................. 
total_duration desc ";`

Comment: The reason is you would have multiple entries for client in payment history. When you try to join Payments history with Cientshared on id_client you get multiple rows returned and hence when you do sum of duration you see wrong numbers. I would suggest to check if you can join with Payments History on some other column alongwith id_client so that you dont get multiple rows returned

Comment: I've altered several ways in `left join` but still no improvement and getting wrong output. i dont know how other ways I could look into this .

Comment: Im not sure how it works but I just removed a `left join` and tried which output the correct value as expected , I update the main question with new solved query.

Answer (score 0):

Finally its solved, Thank you all.

Resolved query:

```html
$sql = "select c.login,cname.Name,cname.LastName,DATE_FORMAT(Creation_Date,'%d-%m-%y')as regdate,DATE_FORMAT((Select max(call_start) from calls where calls.id_client = c.id_client),'%d-%m-%y') as lastcall, c.account_state,sum(cdr.duration / 60) as total_duration from clientsshared as c
left join invoiceclients as cname on cname.IdClient = c.id_client
left join calls as cdr on cdr.id_client = c.id_client
where c.id_reseller='10' group by c.id_client order by total_duration desc limit 100";
```